# ¿Como puedo obtener un valor entre [ ] de un String?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, postgresql

Cuando postgres manda un error, manda un mensaje con un código, ejemplo:

> SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «cargos_index_lower_unique»
>   DETAIL:  Ya existe la llave (lower(nombre::text))=(Ingeniero). (SQL: insert into "cargos" ("nombre", "updated_at", "created_at") values (ingeNiero, 2016-11-08 11:07:58, 2016-11-08 11:07:58) returning "id")

¿Como puedo obtener el valor del "SQLSTATE[23505]"? ¿existe un parametro para el Exception donde pueda hacer eso? o ¿tengo que separar todo lo demas manualmente?

Comment: No deberías mostrar errores de Postgres, para eso Laravel tiene validaciones y puedes mostrar tus propios mensajes. ¿Qué parte de ese string quieres mostrar?

Comment: No se como validar en Laravel eso, pues lo que quiero obtener es el codigo entre los [ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente ejemplo (es eso...un ejemplo):

```
    try
    {
        //aqui tu codigo que genera la exception
    }
    //atrapa la exception de sql
    catch(QueryException $e)
    {
        //...and do whatever you want
        return response()->view('my.error.view', [], 500);    
    }
```

QueryException hereda de PDOException la cual tiene el método getCode donde está el código de error. Con eso no tendrias que parsear ningun string.

Deberia funcionarte.

Comment: Gracias amigo, use el getCode y me funciono para lo que quería. En el documento que me guiaba tenia solo 3 métodos, no sabia que heredaba de PDOException y busque en la web de php.

http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdoexception.php

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de obtener dicho código del string es jugando con las posiciones, un ejemplo básico:

```
$errorMsg = 'SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «cargos_index_lower_unique» ....';

$startPos = strpos($errorMsg, '[') + 1;

$endPos = strpos($errorMsg, ']');

$errorCode = substr($errorMsg, $startPos, $endPos - $startPos);
```